# Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql

Tags: database, localhost

I've full backup from hosting and now want to run on my localhost..
but when i run, i see some error like this :

[image]

```
Warning: include(/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mesindesgalantes/includes/src/Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mesindesgalantes/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 94

#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mesindesgalantes/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php(94): mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'include(/Applic...', '/Applications/M...', 94, Array)
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mesindesgalantes/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php(94): include()
#2 [internal function]: Varien_Autoload->autoload('Zend_Db_Adapter...')
#3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mesindesgalantes/includes/src/Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql.php(30): spl_autoload_call('Zend_Db_Adapter...')
#4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mesindesgalantes/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php(94): include('/Applications/M...')
#5 [internal function]: Varien_Autoload->autoload('Varien_Db_Adapt...')
#6 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mesindesgalantes/includes/src/Magento_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql.php(34): spl_autoload_call('Varien_Db_Adapt...')
#7 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mesindesgalantes/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php(94): include('/Applications/M...')
#8 [internal function]: Varien_Autoload->autoload('Magento_Db_Adap...')
#9 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mesindesgalantes/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Resource.php(175): spl_autoload_call('Magento_Db_Adap...')
#10 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mesindesgalantes/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Array)
#11 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mesindesgalantes/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
#12 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mesindesgalantes/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract.php(350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
#13 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mesindesgalantes/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract.php(335): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
#14 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mesindesgalantes/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Cache.php(53): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#15 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mesindesgalantes/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Cache.php(478): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Cache->getAllOptions()
#16 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mesindesgalantes/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Cache.php(520): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->_initOptions()
#17 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mesindesgalantes/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_App.php(1202): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->canUse('config')
#18 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mesindesgalantes/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Config.php(414): Mage_Core_Model_App->useCache('config')
#19 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mesindesgalantes/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Config.php(294): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_canUseCacheForInit()
#20 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mesindesgalantes/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_App.php(424): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModulesCache()
#21 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mesindesgalantes/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_App.php(354): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#22 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mesindesgalantes/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#23 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mesindesgalantes/index.php(84): Mage::run('', 'store')
#24 {main}
```

Comment: disable compilation from file includes/config.php  comment out last 2 lines by #

#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
#define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');

Answer (score 2):

Step 1. Navigate to the includes/config.php and comment following lines by adding the # at the beginning of the line.

`define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src'); define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');`

then it will look like as

`#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src'); #define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');`

Step 2. Navigate to the var/session and delete all the session files of this folder

Step 3. Navigate to the includes/src and delete all the contents of this folder

Step 4. Navigate to the var/cache and delete all the files and content of this folder

Now you can install it in local machine.

Comment: hanks ! great answer ..

now i have a problem when access the frontend always redirect to real domain not to localhost/myproject .. what happen it?

Comment: you need to change the base url. check this url https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-change-magento-base-urls.html and method number 3

Comment: @IGedeRahmatWijaya, accept it as a answer so that it will helpful for others